# Laravel mongodb not guarding attributes

Tags: mongodb, laravel

Hi guys i'm using jessengers mongodb extension and i've already have a mongodb populate , the problem is that it is showing the guarded attributes , my code is:

**model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
use \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Pessoas extends Eloquent
{
    public $guarded = ['password'];
    public $fillable = ['nome'];

}
```

**Router**

```
Route::get('/pessoas', function () {
    $pessoas = \App\Pessoas::all();
    dd($pessoas);
});
```

**Return**

```
  0 => Pessoas {#147 ▼
      +guarded: array:1 [▶] **<<<< 1 guarded**
      +fillable: array:1 [▶]  **<<<<<< 1 fillable**
      #collection: null
      #primaryKey: "_id"
      #parentRelation: null
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:27 [▶] **<<<<<<< 1 was expected or 26**
      #original: array:27 [▶] **<<<<<< ok**
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but i think you should not use $fillable and $guarded at the same time. $fillable is a whitelist and $guarded a blacklist. You have to choose which behaviour serves you better. AFAIK Laravel only uses one of them if both are specified. (using both creates a undefinied behaviour if a attribute is neither $fillable nor $guarded, so using both makes not much sense)

Answer (score 0):

A query using Jessengers Mongodb extension returns a `Collection` object. Since you're dumping the values of the object, you will see protected and public properties of the object. To prevent this you should use the `toArray()` method on the `Collection` object.

```
Route::get('/pessoas', function () {
    $pessoas = \App\Pessoas::all();
     dd($pessoas->toArray());
});
```